# Objects inside NSAutoreleasePool in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nsautoreleasepool

Is there a way to know the objects that are marked for releasing inside an NSAutoreleasePool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Not to my knowledge, why would you ever want to know this?

Comment: i want to check if a particular object is marked for autorelease?

Comment: i am using code written by someone else and it seems to leak memory returned back from a function, i dont think they have autoreleased the object before returning it.

Comment: Use the Leaks Instrument to check what it thinks is going on. Don't take wild guesses about this stuff. Using that you can easily see who "owns" the object.