# Is there a way to inspect an NSAutoreleasePool's objects?

Tags: objective-c

Just wondering if this is even possible, maybe I could retrieve an `NSSet` of objects that are currently stored in a given `NSAutoreleasePool` instance?

I have looked through Apple's [`NSAutoreleasePool`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html) reference and have not found much pertaining to this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objects inside NSAutoreleasePool in objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181578/objects-inside-nsautoreleasepool-in-objective-c)

Comment: @Kenny [We're tending to let similar questions stand, now.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the purpose is just for debugging, you could use the function `_CFAutoreleasePoolPrintPools()` to print the content of the pool, as documented in [TN2124](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2004/tn2124.html#SECFOUNDATION). It is available since Mac OS X 10.6 and iOS maybe since 3.x.

Alternatively, the class method `[NSAutoreleasePool showPools]` performs the same action.

Comment: Oh wow. This is awesome. In fact, this is **exactly** what I was looking for! :)

Comment: Yeah, this is nice - it pretty-prints a list of objects currently in the pool, but it can't return a collection of objects. :(

Comment: @Jacob: The structure that stores the objects can be retrieved by `pthread_getspecific(0x3e)`, but there is no guarantee that the structure will not be changed across platforms since this is some internal API. Well, since the content is printed to stderr, you could reopen the stream and parse from it to get all the pointers.

Comment: Could you provide an example of that? Thanks.

Comment: Hey guys - is showPools deprecated in 4.2?  I cannot find a mention of it in documentation as existing or ever existing and the compiler does not find it.

Comment: Just for others that stumble across this... showPools is a private class method on NSAutoreleasePool which means it will give you build warnings and won't show up in the list of available methods. Just put in the code and you'll get the contents of the pool on the current thread listed in your debugging output.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not.  The implementation details of `NSAutoreleasePool` are deep black magic.

What you might do instead is to make your own autorelease pool and somehow fool the runtime into thinking that it should use your pool instead of `NSAutoreleasePool`.  But only do this for the thrill of trying it.

### HOWEVER, YOU SHOULD NEVER ALTER AUTORELEASE BEHAVIOR FOR ANYTHING OTHER THAN EXPERIMENTATION AND LEARNING. OTHERWISE I WILL FIND YOU. AND MAKE YOU REWRITE YOUR CODE.

Comment: @Dave I think I *will* do that! :-)

Comment: @Dave **Don't worry - this is all experimental and will never make it into production - I understand the dangers of this, thank you! :P**

Comment: @Jacob I know you'll be fine; this more of a surgeon general's warning to anyone else who comes along and happens to think I might actually be seriously suggesting this.

Comment: @Dave LOL. Surgeon general's warning **indeed**.

Comment: @Dave Here's the question I was talking about last night: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035877/grab-all-values-in-nsdictionary-inside-an-nsarray

Comment: @Jacob yep; `NSExpression` (used internally by `NSPredicate`) ends up calling `-valueForKeyPath:` on the target object, which ends up invoking `-valueForKey:`, which [does some special stuff](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-BBCIBCDJ) for `NSDictionary`.