# Grab all values in NSDictionary inside an NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an NSArray full of NSDictionary objects, and each NSDictionary has a unique ID inside. I want to do lookups of particular dictionaries based on the ID, and get all the information for that dictionary in my own dictionary.

myArray contains:

```
[index 0] myDictionary object
  name = apple,
  weight = 1 pound,
  number = 294,

[index 1] myDictionary object
  name = pear,
  weight = .5 pound,
  number = 149,

[index 3] myDictionary object (etc...)
```

I want to get the name and weight for the second dictionary object (I won't know the index of the object... if there were only two dicts, I could just make a dictionary from `[myArray objectAtIndex:1]`)

So, say I know the number 149. How would I be able to get the second myDictionary object out of myArray into a new NSDictionary?

Comment: Hmm... possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457495 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958622, but I still don't necessarily like the approaches in those answers (haven't read through in depth yet, though). I currently do three or four queries throughout my app in Core Data, but I'd rather just be able to do everything with one array of dicts. Should I use NSPredicate here?

Comment: are the `myDictionary` objects actually `NSDictionary` objects or are they custom objects?

Comment: I think @Chuck's answer is correct in this case, I did *not* know that you could use KVC/`NSPredicate` here, but I think I'm wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As an alternative to Jacob's answer, you could also just ask the dictionary to find the object:

```
NSPredicate *finder = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"number = 149"];
NSDictionary *targetDictionary = [[array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:finder] lastObject];
```

Comment: @Chuck Will that really work? I mean, doesn't the field specified in the `NSPredicate` need to correspond to a method on the current object? Since the objects only respond to `-objectForKey:`, not `-number`, I don't think it'd work, but then again I could be wrong...

Comment: Will try this... I like the idea of doing it this way, since I'm going to have to do this in a few different places, and I hate loops (when I can avoid them).

Comment: @Jacob Relkin: I could be wrong too. I thought NSPredicate used KVC, which works with NSDictionaries and objects. But I can't test the code at the moment.

Comment: @Chuck Oh you mean it'd invoke `valueForKey:` on the `NSDictionary`? Hmm, maybe it actually *would* work... +1 to you!

Comment: @Chuck Nice. I will remember this for future reference! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to iterate through every `NSDictionary` object in your `NSArray`:

```
- (NSDictionary *) findDictByNumber:(NSInteger) num {
   for(NSDictionary *dict in myArray) {
     if([[dict objectForKey:@"number"] intValue] == num) 
        return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[dict objectForKey:@"weight"], @"weight", [dict objectForKey:@"name"], @"name", nil];
   }
   return nil;
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't be too bad, I was hoping to avoid having to do that, though, as I thought this kind of thing would be easier to do (it seems like a pretty common pattern to me...). Well, maybe easier's not the right word - less code, maybe?

Comment: I'm going to try Chuck's method first (in a little bit), and see if it works.